# HTA (VBScript) - Shell.Run using variables

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am trying to create a small program that copies a file to another system. the name of the system is previously selected (is a variable = "testsystem"). I have this Sub and Function:

```
Sub tst
    Dim copythis
    copythis = "xcopy.exe /Y c:\temp\version.bat " & testsystem & "\temp"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Msgbox AddQuotes(copythis)
    objShell.Run AddQuotes(copythis)
End Sub

Function AddQuotes(strInput)
    AddQuotes = Chr(34) & strInput & Chr(34)
End Function
```

The messageBox displays exactly the string that I need: the full command. Also, if I execute the command manually it works:

```
C:\temp>xcopy /Y c:\temp\version.bat \\testsystem3\temp
C:\temp\version.bat
1 File(s) copied
```

I have been battling with this for 2 days now. I guess I am missing some quotes somewhere but can't figure it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing quotes, instead you have to many of them. Your function puts additional double qoutes around the command before it's executed. This causes the entire command string to be interpreted as a single filename (with spaces in it). You'll get the exact same result when you run the command in `cmd` like this:

```
C:\temp>"xcopy /Y c:\temp\version.bat \\testsystem3\temp"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Simply change this line

```
objShell.Run AddQuotes(copythis)
```

into this

```
objShell.Run copythis
```

and the problem should disappear.

If you want to add double qoutes, add them like this:

```
copythis = "xcopy.exe /Y " & AddQuotes("c:\temp\version.bat") & " " _
  & AddQuotes(testsystem & "\temp")
```

Comment: thank you! for some reason I thought that the command in the objShell.Run statement has to be in quotes all the time. didn't even cross my mind to remove them.